# Subsetting a Pandas series

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have a Pandas series. Basically one specific row of a pandas data frame.

```
Name: NY.GDP.PCAP.KD.ZG, dtype: int64
NY.GDP.DEFL.ZS_logdiff       0.341671
NY.GDP.DISC.CN               0.078261
NY.GDP.DISC.KN               0.083890
NY.GDP.FRST.RT.ZS            0.296574
NY.GDP.MINR.RT.ZS            0.264811
NY.GDP.MKTP.CD_logdiff       0.522725
NY.GDP.MKTP.CN_logdiff       0.884601
NY.GDP.MKTP.KD_logdiff       0.990679
NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG            0.992603
NY.GDP.MKTP.KN_logdiff      -0.077253
NY.GDP.MKTP.PP.CD_logDiff    0.856861
NY.GDP.MKTP.PP.KD_logdiff    0.990679
NY.GDP.NGAS.RT.ZS           -0.018126
NY.GDP.PCAP.CD_logdiff       0.523433
NY.GDP.PCAP.KD.ZG            1.000000
NY.GDP.PCAP.KN_logdiff       0.999456
NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.CD_logdff     0.857321
NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.KD_logdiff    0.999456
```

The first column is index as you would find in a series. Now I want to basically get all these index names in a list such that only those index should come whose absolute value in the right column is less than 0.5. To give a context this series is basically a row corresponding to the variable NY.GDP.PCAP.KD.ZG in a correlation matrix and I want to retain this variable along with those variables which have correlation less than 0.5 with this variable. Rest variables I will drop from the dataframe

Currently I do something like this but it also keeps NaN

```
print(tourism[columns].corr().ix[14].where(np.absolute(tourism[columns].corr().ix[14]<0.5)))
```

where tourism is the data frame , columns is the set of columns on which I did correlation analysis and 14 is the row in the correlation matrix corresponding to column mentioned above

gives:

```
NY.GDP.DEFL.ZS_logdiff       0.341671
NY.GDP.DISC.CN               0.078261
NY.GDP.DISC.KN               0.083890
NY.GDP.FRST.RT.ZS            0.296574
NY.GDP.MINR.RT.ZS            0.264811
NY.GDP.MKTP.CD_logdiff            NaN
NY.GDP.MKTP.CN_logdiff            NaN
NY.GDP.MKTP.KD_logdiff            NaN
NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG                 NaN
NY.GDP.MKTP.KN_logdiff      -0.077253
NY.GDP.MKTP.PP.CD_logDiff         NaN
NY.GDP.MKTP.PP.KD_logdiff         NaN
NY.GDP.NGAS.RT.ZS           -0.018126
NY.GDP.PCAP.CD_logdiff            NaN
NY.GDP.PCAP.KD.ZG                 NaN
NY.GDP.PCAP.KN_logdiff            NaN
NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.CD_logdff          NaN
NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.KD_logdiff         NaN
Name: NY.GDP.PCAP.KD.ZG, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

If `x` is your series, then:

```
x[x.abs() < 0.5].index
```

Comment: Nice. It worked. Any idea if I have to keep this variables only in the list of all columns and remove the others, how to do it in simple way?. Like I guess I am looking for something like A-B operation where A is full column list and B is subset. So that A-B gives values there in A but not in B.

Comment: @Manish: You can select those columns with `df[x[x.abs() < 0.5].index]`, where `df` is your DataFrame.

Comment: No this will give me only these columns. There are other columns too in the data frame which I want to keep along these. So what I want to do is like df.columns-(not(x[x.abs() < 0.5].index])

Comment: @Manish: That seems like the opposite of what your first comment said.  In any case, pandas Index objects work that way, so you can do `df.columns - x[x.abs() < 0.5].index`.

Comment: Sorry there wont be a not there. But this is strange. I didn't know pandas index can do set operations. I ended up doing 
dropCol=set(columns)-set(x[x.abs() < 0.5].index)
tourism=tourism.drop(dropCol,axis=1)

Comment: @Manish: Now you seem to be back to the original.  If you take all the columns, get rid of the ones in your <0.5 set, and then drop the resulting ones, isn't that the same as just selecting the ones in the <0.5 set?  You are dropping the complement of your target set, which is the same as just selecting the target set.

Comment: Ah! My bad. Here is what I meant. df.columns is the set of all variables in data frame df. 83 in total.

x[x.abs() < 0.5].index] , here x is just one series of a subset of variables from df. So imagine this. from df. columns I take a subset of columns as below: 
columns=["a","b","c"..18 in no.]

Then on this 18 variables I check which have that 0.5 less than criteria. I get some 8 variables meeting the <0.5 criteria. Then remaining 10 I want to remove from original df.columns.  So in the end df. columns would be 83-10=73.